# getting id of a username in SQLite database Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android app, how can I edit this code to return the id of a username?(I'm using SQLite database)

```
    public int GetId(String username){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=?", new String[]{username});
        return id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the cursor with this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=?", new String[]{username});
```

you must move the cursor's index to its 1st row (if the user exists in the table) and read the `id`:

```
public int GetId(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=?", new String[]{username});
    int id = -1;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) id = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return id;
}
```

If the user was not found the method `GetId()` will return `-1`, so you can check for this value to decide if `username` belongs to an existing user.